# (PHP) How to fetch an array from database column and generate them to check boxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a web app that displays check boxes that was connected to a database, but I can only generate one check box and couldn't generate multiple check boxes based from the array fetched from a database column in mysql.

I tried to generate the multiple check boxes from an array not connected to the database and it worked. I think it has something to do when i fetched an array from the database.

CONTENT OF THE COLUMN ('instrument_name') FROM DATABASE  :

```
("Telephones","White Board","Pen","Video Conference","Screen Projector","Laptops")
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
[] Telephones
[] White Board
[] Pen
[] Eraser
[] Screen Projector
[] Video Conference
[] Laptop
```

THE ERROR

```
[] Telephones
```

(it only generates one check box from the array of the database)

So here's what i've been working on

```
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM mrbs_instrument;"; // Fetch data from table
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      //The array that's not connected to the database
      //$room_inst = array("Telephones","White Board","Pen","Video Conference","Screen Projector","Laptops");

      $room_inst = array($row['instrument_name']); // Fetch data from database column

      // Room Instruments
      echo "<div id=\"rep_type\">\n";
      $params = array('label'         => get_vocab("Intruments") . ":",
              'name'          => 'instruments',
              'value'         => $inst_list,
              'disabled'      => $disabled,
              'options'       => array(),
              'force_assoc'   => TRUE);

      foreach ($room_inst as $i)
      {
          $params['options'][$i] = get_vocab("$i");
      }
      generate_checkbox_group($params); // Generate Checkboxes from Array fetched from database table 
      echo "</div>\n";
```

Where did i go wrong? and i apologize for my mistakes, i just started PHP for a couple of days and new to stack overflow

Comment: `array($row['instrument_name'])` creates an array with one element. You need to split up the string into a separate string for each word.

Comment: You shouldn't put all the words into a single database cell. You should have another table where each word is in its own row, linked to the main table with a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `instrument_name` list into an array. You can use a regular expression to extract the words between quotes.

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"])"/', $row['instrument_name'], $matches);
$room_inst = $matches[1];
```

Comment: nice answer! I needed this too, I was using `implode();` :)